# what does this message mean in streamlit?

Tags: python, pandas, streamlit

i keep getting this error message, but am struggling to find the solution

the code is:

```
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd

# Create a file uploader widget
uploaded_file = st.file_uploader("Choose an Excel file", type="xlsx")

# Check if a file has been uploaded
if uploaded_file is not None:
    # Load the Excel file into a Pandas dataframe
    df = pd.read_excel(uploaded_file)

    # Define the winning criteria for each stat
    age_criteria = (5, 6, 7, 8)
    rating_criteria = (139, float('inf'))
    improving_criteria = True
    won_last_race_criteria = True
    graded_win_criteria = True
    two_wins_this_season_criteria = True
    run_at_course_criteria = True
    top_3_in_betting_criteria = True
    two_wins_over_hurdles_criteria = True
    run_4_times_over_hurdles_criteria = True
    won_twice_over_15_17_furlongs_criteria = True
    ran_over_15_17_furlongs_criteria = True

    # Define a function to calculate the percentage of winning for each horse
    def calculate_percentage(row):
        age = row['Age']
        rating = row['Rating']
        improving = row['Improving']
        won_last_race = row['Won Last Race?']
        if won_last_race == 'y':
            won_last_race = True
        elif won_last_race == 'n':
            won_last_race = False

        graded_win = row['Graded Win?']
        two_wins_this_season = row['Two Wins This Season?']
        run_at_course = row['Run at Course?']
        top_3_in_betting = row['Top 3 in Betting?']
        two_wins_over_hurdles = row['Two Wins Over Hurdles?']
        run_4_times_over_hurdles = row['Run 4 Times Over Hurdles?']
        won_twice_over_15_17_furlongs = row['Won Twice Over 15-17 Furlongs?']
        ran_over_15_17_furlongs = row['Ran Over 15-17 Furlongs?']

        # Calculate the percentage of horses that meet the age criteria
        num_age_criteria_met = int(age in age_criteria)
        age_percentage = num_age_criteria_met * 100 * 9 / 11

        # Calculate the percentage of horses that meet the rating criteria
        num_rating_criteria_met = int(rating >= rating_criteria[0])
        rating_percentage = num_rating_criteria_met * 100 * 9 / 11

        # Calculate the percentage of horses that won the last race
        num_won_last_race_criteria_met = int(won_last_race == won_last_race_criteria)
        won_last_race_percentage = num_won_last_race_criteria_met * 100 * 5 / 11

        # Calculate the percentage of horses that had a graded win
        num_graded_win_criteria_met = int(graded_win == graded_win_criteria)
        graded_win_percentage = num_graded_win_criteria_met * 100 * 7 / 11

        # Calculate the percentage of horses that had two wins this season
        num_two_wins_this_season_criteria_met = int(two_wins_this_season == two_wins_this_season_criteria)
        two_wins_this_season_percentage = num_two_wins_this_season_criteria_met * 100 * 8 / 11

        num_run_at_course_criteria_met = int(run_at_course == run_at_course_criteria)
        run_at_course_percentage = num_run_at_course_criteria_met * 100 * 6 / 11


        # Calculate the percentage of horses that had a top 3 finish in the betting
        num_top_3_in_betting_criteria_met = int(top_3_in_betting == top_3_in_betting_criteria)
        top_3_in_betting_percentage = num_top_3_in_betting_criteria_met * 100 * 7 / 11

        # Calculate the percentage of horses that had two wins over hurdles
        num_two_wins_over_hurdles_criteria_met = int(two_wins_over_hurdles == two_wins_over_hurdles_criteria)
        two_wins_over_hurdles_percentage = num_two_wins_over_hurdles_criteria_met * 100 * 7 / 11

         # Calculate the percentage of horses that ran 4 times over hurdles
        num_run_4_times_over_hurdles_criteria_met = int(run_4_times_over_hurdles == run_4_times_over_hurdles_criteria)
        run_4_times_over_hurdles_percentage = num_run_4_times_over_hurdles_criteria_met * 100 * 6 / 11

        # Calculate the percentage of horses that won twice over 15-17 furlongs
        num_won_twice_over_15_17_furlongs_criteria_met = int(won_twice_over_15_17_furlongs == won_twice_over_15_17_furlongs_criteria)
        won_twice_over_15_17_furlongs_percentage = num_won_twice_over_15_17_furlongs_criteria_met * 100 * 6 / 11


        # Calculate the percentage of horses that ran over 15-17 furlongs
        num_ran_over_15_17_furlongs_criteria_met = int(ran_over_15_17_furlongs == ran_over_15_17_furlongs_criteria)
        ran_over_15_17_furlongs_percentage = num_ran_over_15_17_furlongs_criteria_met * 100 * 6 / 11

        # Calculate the overall percentage
        overall_percentage = age_percentage + rating_percentage + won_last_race_percentage + graded_win_percentage + \
                             two_wins_this_season_percentage + run_at_course_percentage + \
                             top_3_in_betting_percentage + two_wins_over_hurdles_percentage + \
                             run_4_times_over_hurdles_percentage + won_twice_over_15_17_furlongs_percentage + \
                             ran_over_15_17_furlongs_percentage

    return overall_percentage


    # Add a new column with the calculated percentages
    df['Winning Percentage'] = df.apply(calculate_percentage, axis=1)

    # Define color mapping
        color_mapping = {True: 'background-color: green', False: 'background-color: red'}

    # Apply formatting to each column
    formatted_df = df.style.applymap(color_mapping.get, subset=['Age meets criteria?', 'Rating meets criteria?',
                                                                'Won Last Race?', 'Graded Win?',
                                                                'Two Wins This Season?',
                                                                'Run at Course?', 'Top 3 in Betting?',
                                                                'Two Wins Over Hurdles?',
                                                                'Run 4 Times Over Hurdles?',
                                                                'Won Twice Over 15-17 Furlongs?',
                                                                'Ran Over 15-17 Furlongs?', 'Winning Percentage'])

    # Display the formatted dataframe with the new column
    st.dataframe(formatted_df)
```

and this is the error message

```
C:\Users\liamh\PycharmProjects\pythonProject6\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:\Users\liamh\PycharmProjects\pythonProject6\Main.py 
  File "C:\Users\liamh\PycharmProjects\pythonProject6\Main.py", line 131
    color_mapping = {True: 'background-color: green', False: 'background-color: red'}
IndentationError: unexpected indent

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Remove 4 spaces (or 1 Tabulation) from the line 131 just below your comment `# Define color mapping`

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with streamlit.
Have a close look at the error message and you will find the solution:

```py
# Define color mapping
        color_mapping = {True: 'background-color: green', False: 'background-color: red'}
```

This line is over indented, meaning that that it is ill-formatted.
Change it to this:

```py
# Define color mapping
color_mapping = {True: 'background-color: green', False: 'background-color: red'}
```